# Problem in installing pandas in Linux mint

Tags: python, pandas, linux-mint

I am setting up my packages needed to read data for running Machine Learning Algorithms.

I already used the sudo apt-get install command to install the package pandas

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

but i have the error:

```
(ML) suchismita97@suchismita97-H310M-S2-2-0:~/Desktop/SuchiML$ python ./knn.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./knn.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: did you try to use third version of the python `python3 ./knn.py`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using pip? You could then install it by `pip install pandas`, which is the way I've seen it done everywhere. It's the first time I see someone trying to install pandas this way, where did you get it?

Comment: which version of python use? You installed pandas for python3, but, did You run python3?

Comment: @89f3a1c yup my mistake i didnt use pip at first ,  I thought pip won't work in linux ,so I searched other ways to install the packages, but now i have used pip and its working. Thanks everybody for helping out .